# M2Eclipse: Automatically execute Maven when pom.xml changes?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

For an Eclipse plugin project I need a p2 local repository to be automatically deployed with dependencies defined in the pom.

The best way (or the only way that really works) to do so is to use org.reficio plugin `p2-maven-plugin`.

Therefore I created a general project in Eclipse to prepare and hold the repository and a `pom.xml` that generates this repository. 
When I execute the goal `p2:site` the repository is created successfully.

Now I am trying to make Eclipse with M2Eclipse to automatically execute that goal whenever the file `pom.xml` has ben changed (e.g. the user has added a new dependency or the file has been changed because an updated file has been downloaded from the SCM repository.

Is there a way to make M2Eclipse respectively it's Maven Project Builder to execute this phase automatically?

Comment: Using tycho plugin will work...

Comment: First Tycho does not work when you want to run/debug the plugin from within Eclipse which is a major requirement for me. Second Tycho is so badly documented and most of the examples you can find are using deprecated/removed features or are so complex that I don't understand how they are supposed to work. BTW: `p2-maven-plugin` uses tycho internally.

Comment: This works of course. I'm working here in a large OSGi project...

Comment: And how to you make a Maven dependency JAR visible to multiple packages so that you can run your plugin directly from within Eclipse?